# Firefox: images not appearing, url's modified with "pagespeed" + jargon

Tags: html, firefox, pagespeed

OSX 10.8.5

I have images on my site hosted on my own server (not hotlinked) that aren't appearing in Firefox (26.0). It's just empty space where the image should be.

Troubleshooting with Firebug, I found that the image urls are different than what they're supposed to be. Instead of just `src="img/Pic1.gif"` it's something like `src="http://website.net/img/xPic1.gif.pagespeed.ic.A2br4BiDEK.png"`. This *has* to be the reason the images aren't appearing, no?

I [looked up what PageSpeed is](http://wiki.bitnami.com/Components/Apache/PageSpeed), but I've never used it before. I guess I should disable it, but as you can see on the page I linked that it requires knowledge of apache? I have zero knowledge of that and would like to avoid it for the time being if possible.

Does PageSpeed just come as a part of Firebug? I disabled Firebug and refreshed which did not bring the images back. Will other visitors to my site not see the images on Firefox as well? If so, how can I possibly solve this?

**edit**

I'm also using Google Analytics, in case that is relevant..

Comment: Pagespeed is an Apache module that runs on the server - it doesn't come with Firebug (and couldn't as it runs on the server). Most likely your hosting has it enabled by default, not a bad idea, but it's clearly causing issues for you now. I'd contact your hosting company/whoever set up the server and ask them.

Comment: As you say `I have zero knowledge of that` i assume you don't setup your server yourself, but you have a web package that is managed by a website provider, is that right?

Comment: Ah, okay, so I went to my web host/provider and found the PageSpeed option. I disabled it, but it's gonna take a bit to go into effect, so we'll see if pagespeed is the culprit (although now I doubt it is). **edit** left out some words

Answer (score 0):

Pagespeed is not the reason for the disappearance of my images, so although I didn't solve my problem, I'm closing this question as the title is no longer relevant.